# springboot persist without select

Tags: spring-boot

having repository:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<JpaContact, UUID>
```

and respective entity annotated by:

```
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
```

springboot still issues select before insert upon calling:

```
contactRepository.save(new JpaContact);
```

Questions:

1. is there any good reason to fire automatically select before insert? Even if @Id is @GeneratedValue, it won't find anything. If it's not generated value, what's wrong letting db fail on primary key constraint and finding duplicate existency by separate select?
2. How to properly disable this undesirable behavior? I can bypass this only via working directly with EntityManager, but this shouldn't be the proper way.

Comment: To help others if they stumble upon this: 1. @SelectBeforeUpdate(false) seems to have no effect, no idea why. 2. what was the issue in my case is, that CrudRepository has only save method, which uses magic to determine, whether the record is new-being persisted or old-being merged. This is absolutely unnecessary, and having persist/merge just like EntityManager has would do much better job here. You can implement Persistable or EntityInformation to help determine, whether 'save' is 'persist' or 'merge'.

Comment: 3. my bad was, that I was generating UUID manually, and generated UUID @ID field is considered as old-being merged value. So up to my understanding at a time, if you get UUID from client and want to do just persist, you can use insert statement for that, or you can live with extra select before insert, or you can implement interfaces above, or some sort of custom IdGenerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others if they stumble upon this:

1. @SelectBeforeUpdate(false) seems to have no effect, no idea why.
2. what was the issue in my case is, that CrudRepository has only save method, which uses magic to determine, whether the record is new-being persisted or old-being merged. This is absolutely unnecessary, and having persist/merge just like EntityManager has would do much better job here. You can implement Persistable or EntityInformation to help determine, whether 'save' is 'persist' or 'merge'. You have to cooperate, so that magic works.
3. my bad was, that I was generating UUID manually, and generated UUID @ID field is considered as old-being merged value. So up to my understanding at a time, if you get UUID from client and want to do just persist, you can use insert statement for that, or you can live with extra select before insert, or you can implement interfaces above, or some sort of custom IdGenerator. I personally changed the flow, so that UUID is generated at db level and now it works fine.